# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found?

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence, typeerror, chatbot

I am having problems with a very early prototype of a simple chat bot that will use the conversation that it is having to add to a database of responses that it can use later.

```
  import sys,time,random, os.path

typing_speed = 50 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
    print ''

slow_type("Hello! My name is TUTAI, or Turing Test Artificial Intelligance")

slow_type("Currently I am in training, so my features arent fully complete.")

slow_type("If you say something I don't understand yet, I will repeat it back to you in order for me to learn and build a databace of responces!")

talk = raw_input()

talk = talk + ".txt"

existance = True

try:
    talk = open(talk, "r")

except:
    existance = False
    talk.close()

if existance == True:
    talkBack = open(talk, "r")
    print talkBack.read()
```

However, when I run the program, I get this response(yes I checked that the file exists).

```
Hello! My name is TUTAI, or Turing Test Artificial Intelligence
Currently I am in training, so my features aren't fully complete.
If you say something I don't understand yet, I will repeat it back to you in order for me to learn and build a database of responses!
(I type)Hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\TUTAI\firstPythonScript.py", line 31, in <module>
    talkBack = open(talk, "r")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Thank You!
(I know I imported a bunch of stuff I don't need. Pls don't mention that.)

Comment: Did you get this solved? If my answer helped, marking it as such would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by that point in the program, the 'talk' variable is a file handle, not a string. I would discourage the kind of variable re-use seen here as it leads to exactly the problem you are having.

Your code progression:

```
talk = raw_input() #string
talk = talk + '.txt' #string
talk = open(talk, 'r') #file handle
talkBack = open(talk, "r") #error, talk is still file handle
```

Comment: I thought I closed the file using talk.close()?

Comment: It may be a closed file handle, but it's still a file handle and not a string. I would suggest not using the same variable for your filename and file handle. It's hard to give you an example because I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code. You get input from the user, but then use that input as a filename (potential security issues). You also open a file for reading, but never read from it. And in the case where you get an exception opening the file, you attempt to open it again and read from it (which will almost certainly fail).